# Adjacency matrix network x

Tags: python, graph, networkx, adjacency-matrix

Out of a set of data points I am following the routine below:

- points =  [[0,0],[0,1]....[k, l]]
- Delunay triangulation to connect all the points of my data set

```
tri = Delaunay(points)
```

- creation of a graph:

```
G = nx.Graph()
for path in tri.simplices:
    #print(path)
    nx.add_path(G, path)
```

- computation of adjacency matrix:

```
Adj = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense()
```

my question is now... Do are the rows/column of the adjacency matrix sorted in the same order of the points? i.e.

[0,0][0, 0] = Adj_{1,1}
[0,0][0,1] = Adj_{1,2}
etc....

I have to classify the neighbours within my graph and determine their order.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat surprisingly, the answer to your question is **no**. The rows/columns of the adjacency matrix are ordered, by default, according to their order in `G.nodes()`, which is not necessarily the order of the points.

In the [nx documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html) this is stated:

> The rows and columns are ordered according to the nodes in nodelist. If nodelist is None, then the ordering is produced by G.nodes().

And since the order in `G.nodes()` is arbitrary (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35831648/9702190) for example), the order is not necessarily the order of the original point.

You can easily set it to the order of the points by setting the `nodelist` parameter (e.g., `nodelist=sorted(G.nodes())`).

The following code demonstrates this on a simple example:

```
points = np.array([[0,0.], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 0]])
```

The resulting Delaunay triangulation is:

[image]

Using your code with the default, the `G.nodes()` are (at least on my machine): `[(2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 0), (1, 0)]`, and the resulting adjacency matrix is:

```
print(nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense())

[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

However, when using the following code with the `nodelist` parameter we get the requested result:

```
print(nx.adjacency_matrix(G, nodelist=sorted(G.nodes())).todense())

[[0 1 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]]
```